# What this datediff check constraint on SQL table column is verifying?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Can anyone let me know what exactly date difference this below statement is verifying for 
 column check constraint?

```
DATEDIFF(millisecond,[MyDateColumn],
         DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,(0),[MyDateColumn]),(0)))=(0)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `CAST(0 AS DATETIME)` is `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000` (The default value of the `DATETIME` datatype). The integer `0` is implicitly converted to `DATETIME`.
- `datediff(day, (0), [MyDateColumn])` is the difference between the above date in days
- `dateadd(day,datediff(day,(0),[MyDateColumn]),(0))` is the midnight of the given day.
- `datediff(millisecond,[MyDateColumn],dateadd(day,datediff(day,(0),[MyDateColumn]),(0)))` is the elapsed miliseconds since midnight to the given datetime value.

Basically it checks if the value in the column is at midnight. (A constraint to force the `DATETIME` data type to act as a `DATE` column.)